# How to include link url in Alertdialog in .setMessage Android Code

Tags: android, cookies

It is adding a link to the policies of cookies that are stored in external url. But not as adding a link within the text.Help me to add an url in text, to policy url. Thanks

```
@Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    final SharedPreferences settings =
        getSharedPreferences("localPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (settings.getBoolean("isFirstRun", true)) {
      new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Cookies")
        .setMessage("On this site device identifiers are used to personalize content and ads,"
                + " in order to provide social media features and to analyze traffic. "
                + "We also share these identifiers and other information on your device with our social media partners, "
                + "advertising and web analytics./// En este sitio se usan identificadores de dispositivo"
                + " para personalizar el contenido y los anuncios, con el fin de ofrecer funciones de medios sociales"
                + " y para analizar el tráfico. Además, compartimos estos identificadores y otra información"
                + " sobre su dispositivo con nuestros partners de medios sociales,"
                + " de publicidad y de análisis web. http://www.urlaboutcookiepolicy.com")
        .setNeutralButton("Close message", new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            settings.edit().putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).commit();
          }
        }).show();

    }
  }
```

Comment: check my answer u will get an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following code to create hyperlink in dialog.

```
TextView text=new TextView(this);
                text.setText(Html.fromHtml("<ahref=\"http://www.urlaboutcookiepolicy.com \">http://www.urlaboutcookiepolicy.com </a>"));
                text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Cookies")
                .setView(text)
                .setNeutralButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                }).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but I'm assuming you want the URL to be a hyperlink.

You're going to have to define dialog a custom layout: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout

You're then go to need to add `android:autoLink="web"` to your layout.

And finally, just suround your hyperlink with  tags:

```
<a href="http://www.urlaboutcookiepolicy.com">http://www.urlaboutcookiepolicy.com</a>
```